# Best way to convert str 'key: value\r\nkey:value\r\n' to dict, python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following string `"first: 1\r\nsecond: 2\r\n"`, I want to receive following dict `{'first': 1, 'second': 2}`.

How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Francesco I tried to make a list, by splitting str by '\n', and then convert list to dict. But may  there more elegant way?

Comment: Is there not always whitespace between the colon and the value?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the space should be always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

matches = re.findall(r'(\w+):\s*(\d+)', my_string)
# [('first', '1'), ('second', '2')]

matches = [(x[0], int(x[1])) for x in matches]
# [('first', 1), ('second', 2)]

d = dict(matches)
# {'first': 1, 'second': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that there is a space between the colon and the value, split by newlines, then split by whitespace, then convert to integer, then make a dictionary out of the result:

```
s = 'first: 1\r\nsecond: 2\r\n'
result = {k:int(v) for k,v in (item.split() for item in s.strip().split('\r\n'))}
```

Result:

```
>>> result
{'first:': 1, 'second:': 2}
```

If you're not guaranteed to have whitespace between the colon and the value, but you know that it's always a string not containing a colon for the key and an integer for the value, you could try a regular expression:

```
import re
s = 'first: 1\r\nsecond:2\r\n'
result = {k.strip():int(v) for k,v in re.findall(r'([^:]+):\s*(\d+)', s)}
```

Result:

```
>>> result
{'first': 1, 'second': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the split method with a for loop, though I doubt it's the most efficient way to do it :

```
def strToDict(string):
    myDict = {}
    for line in string.strip().split("\r\n"):
        key, val = map(str.strip, line.split(": "))
        myDict[key] = int(val)
    return myDict

strToDict("first: 1\r\nsecond: 2\r\n") # {'first': 1, 'second': 2}
```